# Custom notification sounds not working if app is closed

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, android-notifications

I am trying to implement custom notification sounds. There are two different sounds, one for message and one for call, the sounds work when the app is running and I get a notification but phone's default sound will ring if the app is closed and removed from recent as well. I have used Firebase for notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening mostly as you were getting the notification payload in the push notification. Whenever we get the notification and data both in the fcm payload. Notification tag is always accessed using the system tray of the android system. So it will not consider your custom notification setting.

Try to get only the data in the fcm payload and not the notification.

Comment: after a lot of googling finally it work!

Answer (score 1):

**Notifications work differently in (Android and iOS) and (Foreground and background).**

> 1. Notifications within Android depend on the **notification channel
>    setup and channel ID passed** in the payload.
> 2. Notification customization within iOS depends on the **sound file
>    passed in the payload**.

If you want to set the sound for two different types of notifications in Android, you first need to **create two separate channels and pass the channel ID** with the specific sound while triggering the notification from the backend.

Here is the step-by-step instructions.

**Step 1: Add the Sound File into the IOS resources and Android raw Folder.**

**Step 2: Setup keep.xml File Under Raw Folder.**
[Click here to see the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTuxt.png)

**Step 3: Setup show notification channel function for Foreground.**

```
 AndroidNotificationChannel? channel;

if (message.notification?.body == "You have one Booking Request") {
  channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'Sound', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    description:
        'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.high,
    sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(
        message.notification?.android?.sound),
    playSound: true,
  );
} else {
  channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'normal', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    description:
        'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.high,
    playSound: true,
  );
}
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

Here **Sound** and **normal** are channel ID. There are channels created for different sounds "Sound" and "normal",

> 1. Within **Sound** channel ID, the customized sound will ring
> 2. Within **normal** channel ID, the system default ring will ring when a notification comes.

You can set up many more channels based on your needs There is no limit to creating a channel.

**Note:** Within Android, **once a channel is created from a channel ID, it remains in the same configuration until the application is uninstalled**. Different channel ID can lead to different channel configurations. But remains the same for one channel ID. When the application is in the kill state and a notification arrives from the same channel ID, it automatically takes over the channel ID's configuration like sound, icon, and other customizations from the channel that was created. And there is no need to create a channel ID in iOS

**Step 4: Update your payload from where the notification is created.**

```
const message = {
    token: token,
    notification: {
      title,
      body,
    },
    apns: {
      headers: {
        "apns-priority": "10",
      },
      payload: {
        aps: {
          sound:
            body != "You have one Booking Request"
              ? "default"
              : "ringtone.wav",
        },
      },
    },
    android: {
      priority: "high",
      notification: {
        channelId:
          body != "You have one Booking Request" ? "normal" : "Sound",
        
      },
    },
    data: {
      click_action,
    },
  };
```

From this code, you can extract the example that

1. within iOS you need to **conditionally pass a sound file** to the
   notification client. If you want to play the default notification
   you need to pass the word "default".
2. And within Android, you specifically need to **pass the channel ID** to
   customize the notification. As you can see in the code sound and
   normal are being conditionally passed.

You can integrate two different or more than two types of sound notifications by replacing this **body != "You have one Booking Request" ? "normal" : "Sound"** with a condition as per your requirement.

Boom, now a different notification sound is working whether the app is closed or open